# the tense of a noun clause as a subject of a verb referring to the future

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> He will see the president.   And after that, that he (will see/saw/has seen) the president will surprise his friends.

Which tense of the noun clause, the subject of the verb, in the future time should I use? I think the past tense and the present perfect are okay, but I'm not sure about the first one. Would native speakers use the past tense or the present perfect in the view of the future or the future(will see) dependent from the future time but setting the time of the speaking as the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do.

The plain answer is "that he saw the president". It is viewed from the future time, and refers to a specific event in the past.  You could also use the present perfect.

But in this situation (and most similar contexts) Don't try to structure a sentence like this. You'd be much more understandable if you say

> He will see the president, which will surprise his friends.

or use a gerund (He with "do" to avoid repetition)

> He will see the president. Doing this will surprise his friends.